# Работа idDNSServer и idDNSResolver

Tags: delphi, dns

Добрый день.

Пробую реализовать простенький DNS сервер через `idDNSServer` и `idDNSResolver`.

```
//Запускаем сервер
procedure TMainForm.Button_StartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
MainForm.IdDNSResolver.Host:='8.8.8.8';
MainForm.IdDNSServer.UDPTunnel.OnBeforeQuery:=IdDNSServerUDPTunnelBeforeQuery;
MainForm.IdDNSServer.UDPTunnel.DefaultPort:=53;
MainForm.IdDNSServer.Active:=True;
end;
```

В командной строке Windows набираем `nslookup google.ru 127.0.0.1`

Ловим запрос нашим DNS сервером:

```
//Заменить спец. символы на точки.
function ReplaceSpecSymbol(S: String): String;
var
i: Integer;
begin
for i:=1 to Length(S) do
  if Char(S[i]) in [#1..#31] then
     S[i]:=#46;
Delete(S,1,1); //Убираем первую точку.
S:=Copy(S,1,Pos(#0,S)-1); //Убираем все что после домена.
Result:=S;
end;

//Обработчик события OnBeforeQuery. Срабатывает каждый раз как ловит пакет.
procedure TMainForm.IdDNSServerUDPTunnelBeforeQuery(ABinding: TIdSocketHandle;
  ADNSHeader: TDNSHeader; var ADNSQuery: TIdBytes);
var
S: String;
i: Integer;
ABufferHeader, ABufferQuery: TIdBytes;
h:TResultRecord;
begin
S:=ReplaceSpecSymbol(BytesToString(ADNSQuery,12));
MainForm.Memo_Log.Lines.Add(S);
if Pos('in-addr.arpa',S)=0 then begin
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.QueryType:=[qtA];
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.Resolve(S); //Отправляем наш запрос, через idDNSResolver
   for i:=0 to MainForm.idDNSResolver.QueryResult.Count-1 do begin
      if IdDNSResolver.QueryResult[i].RecType=qtA then begin
         S:=TARecord(IdDNSResolver.QueryResult[i]).IPAddress;
         Memo_Log.Lines.Add('IdDNSResolver qtA: '+S);
      end;
      {//Это просто пробовал получить овтет в формате TXT. Получает.
      if IdDNSResolver.QueryResult[i].RecType=qtTXT then begin
         S:=TTextRecord(IdDNSResolver.QueryResult[i]).Text.Strings[0];
         Memo_Log.Lines.Add('IdDNSResolver qtTXT: '+S);
      end;}
   end;
   //Заменяем заголовки для того что бы совпал ID пакета.
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.ID:=ADNSHeader.ID; //Тут подставляем наш ID.
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.Qr:=1; //Тут ставим 1, помечая тем самым что это ответный пакет.
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.AA:=ADNSHeader.AA;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.ANCount:=ADNSHeader.ANCount;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.ARCount:=ADNSHeader.ARCount;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.BitCode:=ADNSHeader.BitCode;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.NSCount:=ADNSHeader.NSCount;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.OpCode:=ADNSHeader.OpCode;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.QDCount:=ADNSHeader.QDCount;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.RA:=ADNSHeader.RA;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.RCode:=ADNSHeader.RCode;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.RD:=ADNSHeader.RD;
   MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.TC:=ADNSHeader.TC;
   ABufferHeader:=MainForm.IdDNSResolver.DNSHeader.GenerateBinaryHeader; //Переводим заголовок в TidBytes.
   ABufferQuery:=MainForm.IdDNSResolver.InternalQuery; //<<--Ответ это или нет, непонятно!

   //Вот тут отправляем заголовок и ответ, но в командную строку ни чего не приходит.
   ABinding.SendTo(ABinding.PeerIP,ABinding.PeerPort,ABufferHeader+ABufferQuery);
end;
```

Но в командную строку не приходит ответ от нашего DNS сервера.
Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чем конкретно проблема. Ответ вы получили или нет? Если получили, то в чем проблема вывести его? Ссылка не работает.

Comment: Приведите здесь проблемный участок кода.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Все еще актуально.